# Handling incoming JMSCorrelationId in an Apache Camel route

Tags: apache-camel

I have an camel route consuming on a JMS (activemq) queue targeted to be called in a request/reply manner. Inside this route I split the message and invoke another activemq queue (also in a request/reply manner).

Heres a minimal route showing the situation

```
<route>
   <from uri="activemq:A" />
   <split>
      <xpath>/root/subpart</xpath>
      <inOut uri="activemq:B" />
   </split>
</route>
```

The problem is that Camel does not set a new JMSCorrelationId (since there is already one from the incoming message). If nothing is done, you get responses with unknown correlationId's and the exchanges never end.

I didn't go into details but my guess is that the same temporaryQueue is used for the hole splitter but that it (logically)  expects different correlation id's for each of the messages. All using the same, it recieves the first and does not know what to do with the others.

What would be the best solution to handle the situation ?

The one I've found working is to save in another header the incoming JMSCorrelationId (not sure I need to though), and removing it. This is not really as clean as I would want it to be, but I couldn't think of something else. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, your case is described in this [Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5390)  It seems there will be an addition in 2.11 where you can ask Camel to create a new corr-id.

So, in the meantime, why don't you continue what you had working - to remove the JMSCorrelationId header `<removeHeader headerName="JMSCorrelationId" />`  before you send it to "activemq:B"?  I guess that is the best solution for now.

You could, of course, play with the "useMessageIDAsCorrelationID" option as well on the second endpoint.